# Viewing locally hosted webpages on a closed wifi network (no internet) via ios 10

Tags: ios, wifi

For the purposes of a presentation demoing our app, where internet is not available, I need to connect some iPhones and iPads to a local wireless network (an ad hoc network) from which they will access a local web-server (hosted on a macbook) to send / receive data.

In the past this was simple, but it seems iOS 10 is no longer happy connecting to wireless networks that don't allow it to access apple's own servers via the internet.

As a test, I am able to use MAMP Viewer to view my local sites when both my laptop and iPhone are connected to wifi with internet access, but not when both are connected to an ad hoc network created via the macbook. I can see that the host exists, but can't connect to it - MAMP Viewer reports an error (with no details).

Is there a workaround, or is it genuinely the case that iOS 10 devices can only use a wifi network for web data if there's an internet connection back to Apple? Hopefully I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the connection working using an encrypted wifi network offline running from a router, just not an ad hoc network or an unsecured network.